# My code exited after I filled up the priority queue

Tags: c++

The code is about Huffman code.
I typed in "6 a 16 b 5 c 12 d 17 e 10 f 25", to fill in the priority_queue and the program exited without an error.
The priority queue is used to set up a binary search tree for decoding.
I made a function storeBinayNumber() to store the code for each character into an unordered map
called HuffmanCode , which is used for encoding;
and two function encocde() and decode() to encode or decode the string that will be later typed in .
What might be the problem ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Node
{

public:
    char ch = '\0';

    int freq = 0;

    Node *left;

    Node *right;
};

void storeBinaryNumber(Node *root, unordered_map<char, string> &HuffmanCode, string str = '\0')
{

    if (root = nullptr)
        return;

    if (!root->left && !root->right)
        HuffmanCode[root->ch] = str;

    storeBinaryNumber(root->left, HuffmanCode, str + "0");

    storeBinaryNumber(root->right, HuffmanCode, str + "1");
}

void decode(Node *root, Node *current, string str, int index = 0)
{

    if (index > str.length() - 1)
    {

        if (current == root)
        {

            cout << "Decoding suceeded" << endl;

            return;
        }

        else
            cout << "Invalid code" << endl;

        return;
    }

    if (!current->left && !current->right)
    {

        cout << current->ch;

        decode(root, root, str, index + 1);
    }

    else if (str[index] == '0')
    {

        decode(root, current->left, str, index + 1);
    }

    else if (str[index] == '1')
    {

        decode(root, current->right, str, index + 1);
    }
}

void encode(string str, unordered_map<char, string> HuffmanCode)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
    {

        cout << HuffmanCode[str[i]];
    }
}

int main()
{

    int num;

    cin >> num;                                 //6 a 16 b 5 c 12 d 17 e 10 f 25

    auto compare = [](Node *a, Node *b) //lambda expression
    { return a->freq > b->freq; };

    priority_queue<Node *, vector<Node *>, decltype(compare)> q(compare); 

    unordered_map<char, string> HuffmanCode;

    char character;

    int frequency;

    for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++)
    {

        cin >> character >> frequency;

        Node *node = new Node;

        node->ch = character;

        node->freq = frequency;

        node->left = nullptr;

        node->right = nullptr;

        q.push(node);
    }

    Node *root;

    while (q.size() > 1)
    {

        Node *A = q.top();

        q.pop();

        Node *B = q.top();

        q.pop();

        Node *C = new Node;

        C->left = A;

        C->right = B;

        C->freq = A->freq + B->freq;

        if (q.empty())

            root = C;

        q.push(C);
    }

    storeBinaryNumber(root, HuffmanCode);

    int en_or_de;

    string input;

    cout << "press 1 to encode ,  press 2 to decode." << endl;

    cin >> en_or_de;

    cout << "input: " << endl;

    cin >> input;

    if (en_or_de == 1)
    {

        encode(input, HuffmanCode);
    }

    else

        decode(root, root, input);

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code have several bugs:

Assign char type to string won't compile on my compiler

```cpp
void storeBinaryNumber(Node *root, unordered_map<char, string> &HuffmanCode, string str = '\0')
```

The comparison should use `==`, this seems to be a typo.

```cpp
if (root = nullptr)
```

And the `Node` type missed destructor, which needs to a memory leak. After my fix the code seems to work. But it may still have logic bugs.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Node {
 public:
  char ch = '\0';

  int freq = 0;

  ~Node() {
    delete left;
    delete right;
  }

  Node *left;

  Node *right;
};

void storeBinaryNumber(Node *root, unordered_map<char, string> &HuffmanCode,
                       string str = "") {
  if (root == nullptr) return;

  if (!root->left && !root->right) HuffmanCode[root->ch] = str;

  storeBinaryNumber(root->left, HuffmanCode, str + "0");

  storeBinaryNumber(root->right, HuffmanCode, str + "1");
}

void decode(Node *root, Node *current, string str, int index = 0) {
  if (index > str.length() - 1) {
    if (current == root) {
      cout << "Decoding suceeded" << endl;

      return;
    }

    else
      cout << "Invalid code" << endl;

    return;
  }

  if (!current->left && !current->right) {
    cout << current->ch;

    decode(root, root, str, index + 1);
  }

  else if (str[index] == '0') {
    decode(root, current->left, str, index + 1);
  }

  else if (str[index] == '1') {
    decode(root, current->right, str, index + 1);
  }
}

void encode(string str, unordered_map<char, string> HuffmanCode) {
  for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    cout << HuffmanCode[str[i]];
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main() {
  int num;

  cin >> num;  // 6 a 16 b 5 c 12 d 17 e 10 f 25

  auto compare = [](Node *a, Node *b)  // lambda expression
  { return a->freq > b->freq; };

  priority_queue<Node *, vector<Node *>, decltype(compare)> q(compare);

  unordered_map<char, string> HuffmanCode;

  char character;

  int frequency;

  for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
    cin >> character >> frequency;

    Node *node = new Node;

    node->ch = character;

    node->freq = frequency;

    node->left = nullptr;

    node->right = nullptr;

    q.push(node);
  }

  Node *root;

  while (q.size() > 1) {
    Node *A = q.top();

    q.pop();

    Node *B = q.top();

    q.pop();

    Node *C = new Node;

    C->left = A;

    C->right = B;

    C->freq = A->freq + B->freq;

    if (q.empty()) root = C;

    q.push(C);
  }

  storeBinaryNumber(root, HuffmanCode);

  int en_or_de;

  string input;

  cout << "press 1 to encode ,  press 2 to decode." << endl;

  cin >> en_or_de;

  cout << "input: " << endl;

  cin >> input;

  if (en_or_de == 1) {
    encode(input, HuffmanCode);
  }

  else

    decode(root, root, input);

  delete root;
  // system("pause");

  return 0;
}
```